# How to activate and use F-keys (F1, F2, etc..) on a Mac Book Pro Laptop-Keyboard in Gnome-Shell 3.2?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, macbook

I am wondering if there is a shortcut or where and how to active the F-keys on a QWERTZ build-in MBP keyboard.

Any suggestions ?!

Comment: You mean they don't work at all? For example, if you press F11 in your browser it doesn't go fullscreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself! I simply need to use the <kbd>fn</kbd>key, in combination with <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>keys ..

**Reason:** <kbd>F</kbd>keys (Function-keys) are primarily assigned on a Mac for Volume, Brightness, Keyboard-Illumination etc.., therefore "fn" enables the secondary assigned functions of those keys in Ubuntu.

Thank you for asking though GalmWing!