# Questions about Mac Book Pro Keyboard and shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, mac, shortcuts

I have been researching a lot about this and I cannot seem to find any useful information about this topic, what so ever.

I have now been using Ubuntu in one week, and have gotten pretty confident with almost everything. Except keyboard layout and shortcuts. If you know a tutorial or a documents explaining keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu or Linux in general, can you please list it? I use a Mac Book Pro with a Norwegian keyboard, and I have several questions about this:

- Is there a program for having a consist list of absolutely all keyboard shortcuts, and be able to change them?
- How do I use my Fn keys? (<kbd>Fn</kbd> button doesn't do the job for some reason)
- How can I use my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+letter-key-or-number-key or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+letter-key-or-number-key to get fancy characters. (Like I do on Mac OS X)
- How can I swap <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key system wide?

Also I really want to be oriented around this subject, since this is the only thing holding me back on Ubuntu, so if there exists some in-depth material on this, it would be great.

Also, if there exists some programs or material out there making it easier with Mac hardware I would enjoy that.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only part of the solution:

- How do I use my <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys? (Fn button doesn't do the job for some reason)

Try <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, etc..</kbd>, see [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107641/how-to-activate-and-use-f-keys-f1-f2-etc-on-a-mac-book-pro-laptop-keyboard). Also of interest might be this [Ubuntu Documentation: AppleKeyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard) article

- How can I use my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd>-key-or-number-key or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+letter-key-or-number-key to get fancy characters. (Like I do on Mac OS X)

Try "System Setting ➜ Keyboard ➜ Layout Settings ➜ Options" and choose "Keys to choose 3rd level ➜ Right Win" and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>right ⌥</kbd> key, to imitate <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, which should allow what you asked for!

[image]

- How can I swap <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key system wide?

Under "System Setting ➜ Keyboard ➜ Layout Settings ➜ Options" choose "Alt/Win key behavior ➜ Control is mapped to Win keys (and the usual Ctrl keys)" as show in the screen shot below!

[image]

---

For "3rd level keys characters", like <kbd>@</kbd>, <kbd>[]</kbd>, <kbd>|</kbd>, <kbd>~</kbd> if the offered solution above does not work out (seems to be a general problem with Mac Book Keyboard Layouts) you can use [GPaste daemon](https://github.com/Keruspe/GPaste), which is a "Clipboard Manager", that is accessible through user-customized key-shortcut! - Create a list of characters, that are not accessible natively and use the following settings (if you like):

[image]

Simply use Ubuntu Software Center, to download gPaste (by seraching `gpaste`), if it suits your needs!

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question yet?